# How can I paste in NeoVim from an outside source?

Tags: neovim

Like, if I find a text from Wikipedia, for example, and want to copy and paste it to NeoVim, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways to do it:

- paste as usual while in insert mode (ctrl-v/cmd-v)
- paste from the selection registers: + or * (`:help registers`)

  - to paste from a register in insert mode, hit `ctrl-r` then `+`
  - to paste from a register in normal mode, hit `ctrl-"`then `+` then `p`

Additionally, you can substitute `+` with any other register to paste from that register. See what's currently stored by running `:registers`